# Homework Assignment Java Network Programming

Tags: java, network-programming, httpresponse

Here is the assignment verbatim:

> 1.) Write a Java program that is a TCP server that 
>   returns a HTTP response to a browser that displays 
>   the client’s IP address and the number of times it has 
>   connected to the server.
>
> 2.) Test your program with a standard Web browser like 
>   the Internet Explorer.

So far in the class we've been creating servers and clients in java to send images from client to server. We have been using command prompt/terminal to compile and run all programs.

What it seems like to me is we create the Server and Client java programs but this time the client just connects and disconnects and the Server gets the IP address and returns the http response.

Basically what I'm looking for is your interpretation on what to do for the assignment. Also any insight on what a HTTP response exactly is/does would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the HTTP protocol, you might want to look at the [HTTP/1.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment is asking you to write a server that implements the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

As such, you will be able to use any HTTP client, such as Google Chrome.
You don't need to write your own client.

Comment: In fact, if you really are pressed, you can use telnet (but you need to be very good at not mistyping (or backspacing) the HTTP GET request.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like to me is, that you should take the ServerSocket, open up at Port 80 and listen for HTTP requests. They look something like this (source: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

```
GET /infotext.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.net
```

You just could ignore what's in the request and send back a standard HTML page inside your response.
The response should be 200 (success)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Doop-De-Doo
Content-Length: [size]
Content-Language: en
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html> [CONTENT] </html>
```

It's really simple.

Comment: Thanks for editing!
I messed up the new line between the header and the content!